# HttpPost takes more than 3 sec.to get a result

Tags: java, android, json, apache, http

Im facing a very bad/ugly Problem. My Android App needs to send/receive JSON Strings and the Problem is it takes between 3 to 9 Seconds to receive the answer.  The Server responses very quick if i use the Postman Chrome Extension. Here is the Code:

```
public class JSONHandler{
    private HttpClient client;
    private HttpPost post;

    public JSONHandler(){
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        post = new HttpPost("http://secretserver.net/index.php");
        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    }

    private JSONObject sendJSON(JSONObject obj){
        StringEntity se = null;
        try {
            se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
            Log.d("JSON Angekommen",se.toString());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("Encoding", "Exception while encoding");
        }
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            //TODO: Timeout Handling
            String json_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            return new JSONObject(json_string); 

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in this Code i am executing the Method in an Async Task:

```
public class Updater extends AsyncTask<Activity,String,String>{

        private boolean connected;
        private Activity main;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ConnectionHandler conn = new ConnectionHandler(context);
            connected = conn.isConnected();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Activity... acs) {
            main = acs[0];
            String json_String;
            if(connected){
                JSONHandler json = new JSONHandler();
                json_String = json.sendRegister("Peter", "peter@gmx.de", "Feld 2", "Happy", "Developer").toString();
                return json_String;
            }else{
                return "Not Working!";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            Notificator.doNotifyNoClickable(main, "PHP Antwort", result);

            Log.d("JSON", result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure. Maybe you would have better performances by creating your `HttpClient` only once instead of each time you send a JSon request (do you send a lot of them in a row?). When you measured 3 seconds, which pieces of this code were instrumented?

Comment: Um , i plan to send jsons very often but thats currently not implemented. In this case i create only one HttpClient or not ? I am calling the AsyncTask only one time in my current code but it still takes more than 3 seconds

Comment: It would be interesting to determine which part of the code takes so long. I suggest inserting some `System.currentTimeMillis()`-based logs before and after critical operations like contruction of the `JSonHandler`, actual posting of the query, etc.

Comment: (I forgot, regarding the creation of `HttpClient`: the test above will determine whether you need to change anything)

Comment: The Part wich takes so long is between the `Log.d("JSON Angekommen",se.toString());` Line and the `Log.d("JSON", result);` Line so the creation of the Client is not the Problem and also the Notificator class i very fast(I tested the class before). Hope someone knowing that it would be very helpful

Comment: This is too wide, it doesn't allow determining whether this is actually the querying or anything else that takes too long. Also, if you are using a debugger in step mode ('F6' under Eclipse, for example), you may face response time that have nothing in common with the same code running on its own.

Comment: Ok i have no found the Line which takes so long. I wrote that in the  Code `Log.d("JSON","Executing JSON Post");
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
   Log.d("JSON","Executed JSON Post");` And i got this: `15:18:32.140 - Executing JSON Post and then 15:18:36.600 Executed JSON Post`

Comment: Yeah, but LogCat is asynchronous. The timestamp may not be corresponding to the actual event date. So my suggestion to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` in the log message (as the call to Log, on its side, is synchronous of course).

Comment: What kind of network do you use? WLAN, 3G, ...? And does it take as long when sending two requests in sequence without waiting? Is the second call much faster? Do you use SSL? If yes, has the device the correct time?

Comment: Ok i used System.currentTimeMillis and  the difference was round about 1,5 Sec. same with the second call. I use 3G and no SSL

Comment: Can someone help , please ?

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but you could give an alternative library a try and compare performance. It's [DavidWebb](http://hgoebl.github.io/DavidWebb/), a tiny wrapper around `HttpURLConnection`. I've prepared a [gist](https://gist.github.com/hgoebl/9dcb663243db3f5fcbd3) for you.